# Why do convolutional networks work so well for images?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

Convolutional artificial neural networks work well in particular with images. Why?

Comment: Before putting it on hold consider that this was an interview question from a top company in the deep learning industry

Comment: Interview questions are allowed to be vague and broad,  very few interviewers would concern themselves whether their questions were a good fit for Stack Exchange. And that's just fine. It would actually be a shame for the interview if a packaged answer was available online. The question should evaluate your ability to synthesise your own answer from knowledge. If you have specific questions about interactions between images and CNNs perhaps ask one or more of those

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you for this perspective. However looking at my question again it does not seem to be missing anything. It seems quite to the point. My fear is that people in StackExchange in general have overfitted to the attributes that make a question good. This usually consists of medium length body (not small, not large), having a link, having a quotation, having some code <-- This makes a question look good because most good questions do look like this. But is this to say that missing those attributes a question is bad?

Comment: If you want to raise a discussion about why some people think this question is off topic, then it would be better in meta. Ultimately it's down to the community to interpret the site goals and rules. it's entirely possible enough people agree with you to get it reopened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convolution neural networks take into consideration that an image already has a two-dimensional structure. This is a domain knowledge provided by humans and not something the neural network can pick up.

For example, consider if I would give you the raw pixels shuffled in a flattened array (or any other signal for that matter). Would you be able to reconstruct its 2D structure? Probably this would be almost impossible (unless someone builds an algorithm to solve jigsaw puzzles at the pixel level!)

Applying convolution with various strides we are looking for patterns in the patches of the image and not on the individual pixels. Using different strides we are explicitly expressing the amount of resolution that we are investigating the patterns of the image.

So given that these convolution filters are trainable we are able to have an architecture that works well with images. In fact, it would work well with any signal that would have a 2D structure.